What is the meaning of $\sum_{i \cdot j \neq 1}$?
Reading a paper by Cortazar et al. 2006, I stumbled across a type of summation I had not seen before. Equation (17) in their paper states
$
\begin{aligned}
F\left(\mathbf{x}_t, t, T\right)= & \exp \left(x_1(t)+\sum_{i=2}^N \mathrm{e}^{-\kappa_i(T-t)} x_i(t)+\mu t+\left(\mu-\lambda_1+\frac{1}{2} \sigma_1^2\right)(T-t)\right. \\
& \left.-\sum_{i=2}^N \frac{1-\mathrm{e}^{-\kappa_i(T-t)}}{\kappa_i} \lambda_i+\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i \cdot j \neq 1} \sigma_i \sigma_j \rho_{i j} \frac{1-\mathrm{e}^{-\left(\kappa_i+\kappa_j\right)(T-t)}}{\kappa_i+\kappa_j}\right)
\end{aligned}
$
How should I interpret $\sum_{i \cdot j \neq 1}$ here?

I don't know the paper, but I suppose $i \cdot j \ne 1$ means $i,j \ne 1$ and $i,j \ne -1$ i.e the dot product is not one

Check the paper's Appendix for the derivation. I think it means summing over $(i,j)\in {1,\dots,N}\times  {1,\dots,N}$ except $i\neq 1$ and $j\neq 1$.

You can infer (from the Appendix A at the end of the article for example) that this is meant to be a sum over all couples $(i,j)$ of integers such that $i$ times $j$ is different from $1$ (multiplication is what the dot represents), which is equivalent to $i \neq 1$ or $j \neq 1$ since we are dealing with positive integers.
In general, sums may be defined over indexing sets whose elements satisfy a certain property, and not necessarily "connected" sets. For example you could sum over prime numbers.

An easier way to describe the couples would be all $(i,j)$ expect $i=j=1$ (assuming $i,j$ are both positive integers).

Thanks for the answer, Bruno!

@quarague For sure. The notation I would have had in mind as more "usual" is definitely $\sum_{(i,j) \neq (1,1)}$ or something akin to that.
